Can AI be used to *ask* questions without disclosure here?
I like using AI as a productivity boost. If I have a question on this forum, I could have AI write the question’s initial draft with the relevant Scriptures, and then I’ll polish it up from there before submitting it. However, I’ve read up on Christianity’s policy of allowing generative AI content on the site so long as you follow disclosure procedures:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/gen-ai-policy
Does the disclosure requirement apply if I use generative AI in writing a question (as opposed to an answer or comment)?
P.S. I did not use AI in writing this question. ;)

I don't think that's likely, but I'm also not sure how you'd use it to ask questions. Please [edit] this to explain.

Also I didn't know that policy was on this site! I don't agree with it. If it was up to me even disclosed AI use (other than proofreading) would be deleted. The community might need to officially request for it to be changed.

One would have to possess a fairly good grasp of both the subject and the detail of the question in  order for an AI program to come back with more than just a vague and generic summary. Particularly in spiritual matters where AI is going to pick up a wide spectrum of opinions without the ability to focus on genuinely spiritual expressions.

@curiousdannii I have edited the question for clarity. Thanks!

I can see the use of using gen ai in an assistive capacity to make up for a language barrier or find some nuance in a question that would otherwise be hard for one to grasp having limited knowledge of the subject area.
However, if you can't understand the question well enough to write it in the first place, it stands to reason that you're not going to understand the answer.

I just like using AI as a productivity boost. On this forum, I could have AI write the question’s initial draft with the relevant Scriptures, and then I’ll polish it up from there. Would I still need to disclose that AI was used—even if it’s just a question, as opposed to an answer?

@TheEditor with that usage absolutely.

@curiousdannii “Absolutely” meaning I’d absolutely need to disclose that AI was used?

@TheEditor Yes that's what I meant. And you should probably expect to receive some downvotes for it. This community is not generally in favour of GenAI.

@curiousdannii I understand. While I disagree with the decision since I judge a question’s value by the final product, not how it got there, I will comply with the community’s decision. Thanks for letting me know.

@curiousdannii As a follow‐up, what if I did the reverse, where I hand‐type the draft of a question but use AI to polish it? While I can’t imagine that adopting Grammarly’s underlined suggestions would require disclosure, what if I used, say, ChatGPT to polish a question? (I’m guessing that disclosure would be required to use ChatGPT for revision purposes as well, but I thought I’d ask to be sure.)

@curiousdannii I'm really only against using GenAI to do things that I would consider cheating.  Using AI for a tool to help write better is no worse than using Grammerly (which, I'm guessing has always used machine learning) - we wouldn't require users to disclose using that, right?

@Peter Yes agreed. What we don't want is undisclosed use of AI that helps with the content of posts. If we can't tell that it helped with proofreading then it doesn't need to be disclosed.
